# Angularjs app scope variable not available to the view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

In my angularjs code below why is the IsLoggedIn and Username not available to the view. Not sure what's wrong, any help will be highly appreciated:

```
'use strict';

myApp.controller('masterPageController',

    function masterPageController($scope, loginService, stateService) {

        $scope.State = stateService.State;

});

myApp.factory('stateService', function () {

    // todo: fetch the state from server when the service is initialised
     var state = {};

    return {
        State: state,
    };
});

myApp.factory('loginService', function ($http, $q, stateService) {


    return {

        Login: function (logindetails) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http({ method: 'POST', url: '/api/Login/Login', data: JSON.stringify(logindetails), headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }).
               success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                   stateService.State = data.State;
                   deferred.resolve(data);

               }).
               error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                   deferred.reject(status);
               });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
});

<div ng-controller="masterPageController">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <a href="/logout" ng-show="State.IsLoggedIn" >{{ State.Username }}</a>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: It doesn't work when I set the stateService.State property in my loginService

Comment: works for me [**plnkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/zx1BO4936fn2hI8wyYIW?p=preview)

Comment: You are going to need to look at the debugger. I don't have the loginservice stuff so I took it out but it appears to be working in my bin: http://jsbin.com/ruvit/1/

Comment: I didn't see anything problem in the code you posted. You might want to create a plunker to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Change the way you build the service from "factory" to "service" and define "state" on this and do not return anything.

myApp.service('stateService', function () {

```
// todo: fetch the state from server when the service is initialised
 this.state = {};
```

});

http://codepen.io/rotempe4/pen/KNMpzZ